# How to test for a passed function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

doc is an instance of pdfkit document...

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
const doc = new PDFDocument()
```

...which gets passed to my function:

```
export const outputTitle = (doc, title) => {
  if (!title) return null

  doc
    .fontSize(15)
    .font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .text(title, 380, 160)
}
```

Now I need to write unit tests for this functions using jest.

```
describe('outputTitle()', () => {
  const doc = jest.fn()

  test('should return null if parameter title is missing', () => {
    // SETUP
    const title = undefined
    // EXECUTE
    const result = outputTitle(doc, title)
    // VERIFY
    expect(result).toBeNull()
  })

  test('should call doc()', () => {
    // ???
  })
})
```

But how do I test the second part, which is the case of passing a title value?
I think my mock of `doc` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe('outputTitle()', () => {
  const textSpy = jest.spyOn(doc, 'text');

  test('should call doc with title', () => {
      outputTitle(doc, 'some title');

      expect(textSpy).toBeCalledWith('some title');
    });
})
```

[Reference](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/blob/master/tests/unit/document.spec.js)

Comment: But this is not testing my chain of doc. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: I have never used pdfkit but that is how you test functions and track calls to that function in jest.

Comment: Sure, but my function, which I'll try to test is using the passed variable 'doc' instead of a `new PDFDocument`

Comment: attached some tests as Refernce from pdfkit that might be helpful

Comment: Edited my answer to incorporate passed doc

Comment: Ok, but where do you execute the function `outputTitle()`?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194025/discussion-between-user3142695-and-nooruddin-khorasi).